# creating volume error on docker for windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

what does this error means? how to resolve it ?

E:\krishna\concordia_updated>docker-compose up
Creating volume "concordia_updated_db_volume" with default driver
ERROR: create concordia_updated_db_volume: volume name "concordia_updated_db_volume" cannot be a reserved word for Windows filenames

E:\krishna\concordia_updated>

Comment: Can you post your docker-compose.yml file as well so that we can help you ? Which version of docker-compose are you using ?

Comment: It maybe has to do with this issue: Certain file names on Windows are causing troubles. More specifically names equal to reserved words or starting with reserved words, one of them is CON. can you try to change on of the first 3 letters to see if that solves your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue when creating a `Config Server` for MongoDB, via docker. The issue which you are facing is due to the folder named `concordia_updated`. Since you are running `docker-compose` directly from that folder, hence docker is trying to create a volume on your local machine which is named as **`FolderNameFromWhichDockerComposeIsCalled_VolumeNameInYourYamlFile`**. In your case, docker is trying to create a volume named `concordia_updated_db_volume` on you local windows machine. It is due to the presence of CON in the volume name that your command is failing. [A folder can't be name CON in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/86999/why-cant-i-name-a-folder-or-file-con-in-windows), but looks like it doesn't work for anything starting with CON too.

The Solution would be to rename your folder `concordia_updated` to `cncordia_updated` or any other name that doesn't start with CON. In my case I changed the ***configserver*** folder name to ***cfgsvr*** and it worked.